# How do I put just text onto a Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

In leaflet we have api calls and plugins to put placemarks, icons, images and geometric shapes. Yet I have no idea how to put just a piece of text. What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a `L.Marker` with a `L.DivIcon`?

> Represents a lightweight icon for markers that uses a simple  element instead of an image. Inherits from Icon but ignores the iconUrl and shadow options.

Reference: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#divicon

```
new L.marker([0, 0], {
    icon: new L.DivIcon({
        html: '<h1>Some text...</h1>'
    })
});
```

Comment: Somehow it was hard to understand that you can go from marker to icon and then to the so called "DivIcon" with complete html support. In my opinion that's a strange API design.